# A Simple (but long) SQLAlchemy filter() runs extremely slow (SQL Server)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Summary: I am running a simple (but long) query where I am getting all rows that match an entry within a list a source_id/owner_id pairs. There's no joins, nothing complex. The SQL statement generated by SQLAlchemy takes ~200ms when run directly, but takes over 2 minutes when run through SQLAlchemy.

My model class:

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "my_database.dbo"}
    __tablename__ = "tblMyModel"

    source_id = Column("SourceID", INT, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column("OwnerID", INT, primary_key=True)
    part_number = Column("PartNumber", NVARCHAR(64), nullable=False)
```

The query:

```
class ModelKey(NamedTuple):
    source_id: int
    owner_id: int

def get_by_ids(
    session: Session, id_keys: Set[ModelKey]
) -> List[MyModel]:
    filters = [
        and_(
            MyModel.source_id == key.source_id,
            MyModel.owner_id == key.owner_id,
        )
        for key in id_keys
    ]
    query = session.query(MyModel).filter(or_(*filters))
    result = query.all()
    return result
```

(We pass the session into this method because we are doing session management across several queries and inserts. Prior to `get_by_ids()` being called, there's a few other SQL queries being called, but no insert operations.)

`id_keys` can have up to 400 entries in it. I've checked the SQL statement generated by SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT 
    my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.SourceID,
    my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.OwnerID,
    my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.PartNumber 
FROM my_database.dbo.tblMyModel 
WHERE 
     my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.SourceID = 18396 AND my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.OwnerID = 99312703
     OR my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.SourceID = 18396 AND my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.OwnerID = 99255569
     OR my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.SourceID = 34512 AND my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.OwnerID = 8675309
...
     OR my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.SourceID = 36785 AND my_database.dbo.tblMyModel.OwnerID = 1234567
```

This is a long query (464 `OR` clauses) but if I take the SQL statement generated by SQLAlchemy and run it directly in DBeaver, it executes in about 200ms, whereas SQLAlchemy running the same query against the same database takes over 2 minutes.

I profiled my code using the [SQLAlchemy suggetions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/performance.html#code-profiling) and found the following:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1  113.133  113.133  113.133  113.133 {method 'execute' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
        1    3.578    3.578    3.578    3.578 {method 'fetchall' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
        1    0.033    0.033    0.035    0.035 selectable.py:3144(_froms)
    18348    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        1    0.005    0.005    0.005    0.005 {method 'close' of 'pyodbc.Cursor' objects}
      930    0.005    0.000    0.014    0.000 elements.py:965(__init__)
      930    0.005    0.000    0.008    0.000 elements.py:3251(__init__)
      933    0.005    0.000    0.013    0.000 compiler.py:866(visit_column)
      930    0.004    0.000    0.037    0.000 compiler.py:1361(_generate_generic_binary)
   3264/1    0.004    0.000    0.086    0.086 visitors.py:87(_compiler_dispatch)
```

According to SQLAlchemy's documentation "this would indicate that the database is taking a long time to start returning results, and it means your query should be optimized, either by adding indexes or restructuring the query and/or underlying schema." But as I said, the query itself runs very quickly when run outside of SQLAlchemy.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That many `OR` clauses is always going to be difficult. Probably one version of the query the optimizer is able to transform it to a join on a `VALUES` table, and another version not. Looks like you should use a two-columnTable-Valued Parameter or a temp table, and join that instead.

Comment: I wonder if it inlines the values to the query or not when run vs. sending the query with placeholders, and if that could affect the query plan.

Comment: Ilja that's a very good question, looking at the query in our DataDog dashboard shows `WHERE my_database.dbo. [ tblMyModel ] . [ SourceID ] = ? AND my_database.dbo. [ tblMyModel ] . [ OwnerID ] = ? OR ...` but I don't know if that is DataDog formatting the query or not.

When I compiled the sqlalchemy query into SQL I called `query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))` which may differ from the actual query since I set `literal_binds` to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this by using OPENJSON:

```py
class ModelKey(NamedTuple):
    source_id: int
    owner_id: int

def get_by_ids(
    session: Session, id_keys: Set[ModelKey]
) -> List[MyModel]:
        key_dicts = [
            {"source_id": key.source_id, "owner_id": key.owner_id}
            for key in id_keys
        ]

        json_params = json.dumps(list(key_dicts))

        sql = text(
            """
            SELECT tmm.SourceID , tmm.OwnerID, tmm.PartNumber
            FROM OPENJSON( :json) WITH (
                source_id INT '$.source_id',
                owner_id INT '$.owner_id'
            ) as json
            INNER JOIN my_database.dbo.tblMyModel tmm
            ON json.source_id = tmm.SourceID AND json.owner_id = tmm.OwnerID
            """
        ).params(json=json_params)
        result = session.execute(sql).fetchall()

        models = []
        for row in result:
            row_dict = dict(row.items())
            m = MyModel(
                source_id=row_dict["SourceID"],
                owner_id=row_dict["OwnerID"],
                part_number=row_dict["PartNumber"],
            )
            models.append(m)

        return models
```

This version of the query (executed in SQLAlchemy) takes about 5ms, which is a massive improvement over the original version, which took about two minutes. (This is running with the same `id_keys` on the same hardware.)

I still don't know *why* the original version was so slow and would like to, if anyone has any insight.